Can we handle exceptions in the ros2_control control loop thread safe methods read, update, and write in a custom robot without real-time constraints?
For example, to use try/catch blocks inside these methods

Catching exception pointers in c++ from another thread is possible, see here. Therefore you can catch them using try and catch.
Real-Time-Constraints are a different topic though - generally speaking ROS2 addresses RT in one of its tutorials.

Thanks @EricScöerg, but my question is specifically to the ros2_control framework. I will update the title

I don't know why it should not be possible.
We integrated try-catch blocks around the realtime methods of controllers and hardware components.

Thank you @christoph. But this is exactly the reason for my question. Why the try/catch blocks were not in the initial design of the ros2_control? Was there any concern about using exception handling in compromising the determinism of real-time systems?

Afaik it was missing because just nobody thought about that. Now itt turned out that people write code that explodes or have exceptions and the controller_manager blew up.. this is why we added that now
